# Quotient space between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Is the quotient map between topological spaces always continuous? If this is not the case, what conditions need to be satisfied for this to be true? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a quotient map is by definition continuous.  Specifically, a map $f:X\to Y$ is a quotient map if it is continuous, surjective, and the topology on $Y$ is the finest topology for which $f$ is continuous.